# latex: why the \sum Symbol will disappear?

Tags: sum, latex

I am really confused why the \sum symbol will be disappeared after a few times of compiling. It was normally displayed previously, but now it appears as the following:
[image]

where the denominator in this equation is a sum from i-1 to n of AIan

My current packages used are as followings:

```
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{amssymb} 
%\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsxtra}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} % For algorithms

\usepackage{verbatim} % For comment
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

Could anyone help me fix this problem? I have tried many different solutions, but the sum symbol still could not be displayed normally.

Comment: I suggest you post your question in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) instead as it will reach the target audience better.  When you do, I suggest you create a minimal working example.  For example, remove the irrelevant `\usepackage` and have the `\begin{document}` and \end{document}` so that it compiles such that you still see your problem.  Also include the line in question as you've shown the output but not what you're entering.  It'll help others help you and you might even figure out the cause.

Comment: Yes, post minimal code that we can compile to reproduce the problem. You wrote that the \sum symbol disappeared after compiling a few times: have you tried to delete aux files (.log, .aux, etc.) and compile again? This may help, let us know in comments!

Comment: I had the same problem, the conflict is produced by the `fontenc` package, replacing it by the `inputenc` package solves the problem. That is, you have to replace `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`
by `\usepackage{inputenc}`